# Submitting a form that has the action attribute set and in the same time there is a javascript code that handles the submitting

Tags: php, javascript, html, form-submit

what happens when you submit a form that has the action attribute set and in the same time there is a javascript code that handles the submitting?

Any way to maintain both codes (action attribute and javascript code) for the case the user doesn't have javascript installed?

Regards

Javi

Comment: You'll have to handle the server side handling and (especially the) response to deal with both situations. I think you should edit your question and tags to get a decent answer about server side code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not much control you have when javascript is disabled. You can however, use [`<noscript></noscript>` tags](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_noscript.asp) to imply that javascript should be enabled for the functionality of the page. Note that you can also change the `action` attribute with javascript like  this:

```
yourformName.action = 'new action here';
```

But of course that won't work if javascript is disabled.

You should develop your page keeping in mind [graceful degradation](http://accessites.org/site/2007/02/graceful-degradation-progressive-enhancement/) which means when certain feature isn't there, your page should still behave normally at least. It is upto you how you code your page. I would prefer a submit button in such case to be there always so that a form is submitted whether or not javascript is enabled.

Comment: Please bare in mind that elements within `<noscript>` aren't visible when extensions like NoScript block JavaScript execution.

Answer (score 2):

> what happens when you submit a form that has the action attribute set 
>   and in the same time there is a javascript code that handles the submitting?

That depends on what you mean by "javascript code that handles the submitting". Assuming you mean "You call the `submit()` method of the form object", then the browser will submit the form as normal to the specified URI.

> Any way to maintain both codes (action attribute and javascript code) for the case the user doesn't have javascript installed?

Use [progressive enhancement](http://icant.co.uk/articles/pragmatic-progressive-enhancement/).

Write a form that works without JavaScript, then wrap it with JS event handlers that do alternative functions (and cancel default submission if you don't want that).